# Tensorflow uses only GPU0

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

Test code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)
tf.config.set_soft_device_placement(False)

device = '/GPU:1'
with tf.device(device):
    print("Input device : " + device)
    a = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])
    b = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0]])

c = tf.matmul(a, b)
print(c)
```

Current behavior
I am trying to define scope of code for GPU1. However, the code is executed on GPU 0.
For example, output of the test code given above is

```
Input device : /GPU:1
2020-08-29 00:15:42.093921: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:574] Executing op MatMul in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-08-29 00:15:42.094117: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10.0
tf.Tensor(
[[22. 28.]
[49. 64.]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32)
```

Both GPUS 0 and 1 are available

Expected behavior
The code should be executed on GPU 1

System information

```
OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 16.04): Linux
Mobile device (e.g. iPhone 8, Pixel 2, Samsung Galaxy) if the issue happens on mobile device: na
TensorFlow installed from (source or binary): conda
TensorFlow version (use command below): 2.0.0
Python version: 3.6.5
CUDA/cuDNN version: 7.6.5
```

GPU model and memory:

```
name: "/device:GPU:0"
device_type: "GPU"
memory_limit: 32040203060
physical_device_desc: "device: 0, name: Tesla V100-SXM2-32GB, pci bus id: 0000:61:00.0, compute capability: 7.0"
name: "/device:GPU:1"
device_type: "GPU"
memory_limit: 32040203060
physical_device_desc: "device: 1, name: Tesla V100-SXM2-32GB, pci bus id: 0000:62:00.0, compute capability: 7.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Some easy lines to handle a situation where you might not want TF to even know there are other GPUs are by setting environment variables. For example

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="3" # sets only GPU3 to be visible
os.environ["TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH"]="true"
```

Also note that the TF tutorial has this line instead of what you are using:

```
with tf.device('/device:GPU:2'): # It includes /device:... in the device name
```

Perhaps give the second option a try first, but the top one will lock your session into only using the one GPU. You would call it before using TF.

Comment: Yes, I tried the above name format but the results is the same.

Comment: If we set CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1 then it becomes the device 0 for my code. But what I need it when both devices 0 and 1 are available, it should allocate specific jobs to 0 and specific to 1.

Answer (score 0):

you can choose what gpu to use from terminal while running python file like this:

```
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1 python app.py
```

Comment: If we set CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1 then it becomes the device 0 for my code. But what I need it when both devices 0 and 1 are available, it should allocate specific jobs to 0 and specific to 1.

Answer (score 0):

The statement for calculating c was indented so it was allocating the calculation to the default machine GPU0.